# Python: how to generate signed URL with custom policy cloudfront

Tags: python, amazon-cloudfront, boto

I have some code that generates a signed URL

```
expire_time = in_an_hour()
conn = CloudFrontConnection(access_key_id, access_key)

##enter the id or domain name to select a distribution
distribution = Distribution(connection=conn, config=None, domain_name=domain, id=dist_id, last_modified_time=None, status='')
signed_url = distribution.create_signed_url(url=url_tosign, keypair_id=keypair,expire_time=expire_time,private_key_file="/path/to/priv.pem")
return signed_url
```

I want to include a custom policy that takes into account user IP. I wrote a method to generate the json that works fine. I tried adding `policy=get_policy(url_tosign, ip)` to the `distribution.create_signed_url` call, but I just get an error saying it's an unexpected keyword argument. How can I modify this code to generate my signed URL with source IP restrictions?

Comment: You need to create a policy first, https://kite.com/python/docs/boto.cloudfront.distribution.Distribution.create_signed_url       params = self._create_signing_params(
                     url=url, keypair_id=keypair_id, expire_time=expire_time,
                     valid_after_time=valid_after_time, ip_address=ip_address,
                     policy_url=policy_url, private_key_file=private_key_file,
                     private_key_string=private_key_string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Dean's link had the solution. There is an `ip_address` parameter that we can use.

Updated line of code

```
signed_url = distribution.create_signed_url(url=url_tosign, keypair_id=keypair,expire_time=expire_time,private_key_file="/path/to/priv.pem", ip_address= "x.x.x.x/32") # CIDR notation optional. x.x.x.x also works as a /32
```